# How to divert a program invocation to a running instance

Tags: java

**Given** the source code of a Java application with a GUI

**when** I compile it
**and** invoke it twice, i.e. the second invocation while the first instance is still running

**then** I would like my second invocation (and its command line arguments) to be diverted to the instance already running.

How can I modify the source code to achieve this?

I noticed that Eclipse Java IDE is capable of this:

```
eclipse some.txt
eclipse other.txt
```

will be on different tabs of the same window. If someone knows, which part of the source does this and where to find it, that would already help me.

Comment: Eclipse starts with a process ID and the operating system knows which instance to divert new processes to. In Java, all applications would run under the `java` process since they are under the JVM, so there is no straightforward way to direct way to do what you want with a Java app.

Comment: @cricket_007 But isn't Eclipse written in Java? https://www.openhub.net/p/eclipse

Comment: Yes, it is written in Java, but it is built into binary executables for specific platforms (Windows, OSX, Unix) so those operating systems can manage it as a standalone application.

Comment: @cricket_007 I see, quite nifty, thanks!

Comment: @cricket_007 Every `java` invocation is a standalone process with its own PID and everything. Applications share single JVM only is special cases, like when run inside some container (Tomcat, for example).

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [JUnique](http://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/junique/). From the home page:

> The JUnique library can be used to prevent a user to run at the same
>   time more instances of the same Java application.
>
> JUnique implements locks and communication channels shared between all
>   the JVM instances launched by the same user.

Use it with maven:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>it.sauronsoftware</groupId>
        <artifactId>junique</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

You can use `JUnique.sendMessage` from the second instance to pass the new arguments to the allready existing instance. The allready existing instance have to implement a `MessageHandler` for that. See the [quick start](http://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/junique/manual.php?) from the manuel.